# How to achieve something similar to this picture?

Tags: modeling

[image: Here this is a globe with a uni hat on top. I want to achieve something like this with the same set of segments and rings but very smooth]

I am new to Blender. I am trying to make it as in the picture, so basically a globe similar to this with the same structure but very smooth. And above this globe, there is a graduation hat. I tried using a UV sphere, but when I am trying to achieve the same segments and rings its not that smooth and it does not become a sphere. Help me with this community. Please

Answer (score 5):

Not totally similar, but much more simple:

[image]

Create flat part showed in edit mode. This is half part of the eighth of the sphere.

Mirror it to have the bottom part.

Bevel.

Array eight times as the sphere is composed of eight times of this.

Subdivide (with simple option).

Add two simple deform (bend) to turn it as a sphere.

Weld to join the array extremities.

[image] (Blender 4.0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did the globe part and made the base for that too. But now I want to connect these 2 objects forming a natural stand for this. But when I just use the boolean it doesn't feel natural because of the very sharp connection and when I try to give the connection a bevel it's not working as I expected. Can you help me with that too?

Answer (score 4):

Create a 64 x 32 UV sphere, only keep 1/32, mirror it on X and Z:

[image]

Give it an *Array* modifier with an empty as *Object Offset*, enable *Merge* and *First and Last *rotate the empty 45° to have a full globe:

[image]

Cut this edge with the knife:

[image]

Select these faces:

[image]

Extrude along normals with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, make sure that the merge *Distance* of the *Array* modifier is enough:

[image]

Remove the inner faces:

[image]

Right click > *Shade Smooth* then Auto Smooth:

[image]

When you're glad, duplicate your object, apply the modifiers of the copy:

[image]

Rework the topology...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but about the hat. I got some idea about it and can you share the file if possible?
Thank you very much for your swift reply.

Comment: You should be able to edit your original post to add text or images